# Как и где сохранять данные в Realm при первом запуске программы

Tags: android, база-данных, realm

Где нужно разместить код, чтобы данные **НЕ** перезаписывались и добавлялись несколько раз? То есть, мне нужно сохранить данные в риалм **только один раз** при первом запуске, используя такой код:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        Task item = new Task();
        item.setName("Item1");
        item.setSubname("SubItem1");
        item.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        item.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.copyToRealm(item);
        realm.commitTransaction();
        realm.close();
```

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
boolean isFirstStart = prefs.getBoolean("first_start", true);
if (isFirstStart) {
    // очистка БД (если юзер закроет приложение но данные до конца не вставятся)
    // ваш код вставки в БД
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("first_start", false).apply();
}
```

Да, можно бы было сделать проверку на пустую БД, но вдруг данные не успеют вставиться все и юзер закроет приложение? Поэтому я за такой способ, "в лоб".

Comment: не получается сделать import SharedPreferencesManager, также ошибка на context

Comment: @Julia context - это контекст. Вы про него не знаете? Если вы пишете код в активности то можете в качестве него передать `this`

Comment: А по поводу импорта я опечатку сделал. Ответ изменил. Если снова ошибка будет то напишите код сами, вам предложит IDE нужный класс)

Answer (score 3):

Допустим у вас есть класс StoredUser

```
StoredUser storedUser;
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
storedUser = Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(StoredUser.class).findFirst();
    if(storedUser!=null){
        //объект сохранен
    }else{
        Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                storedUser = realm.createObject(StoredUser.class);
                storedUser.someField(true);
            }
        });
    }
```